# Spring boot 2.6 actuator info

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using actuator and in the application.properties file i have the following fields

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.info.defaults.enabled=true
```

when I call the url `/actuator` I see

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://localhost:8443/actuator","templated":false},"health":{"href":"https://localhost:8443/actuator/health","templated":false},"health-path":{"href":"https://localhost:8443/actuator/health/{*path}","templated":true},"info":{"href":"https://localhost:8443/actuator/info","templated":false}}}
```

but when I call `/actuator/info` it returns me `{}`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "info":{"href":"https://localhost:8443/actuator/info","templated":false} --> This field shows value, it should return {"templated":false} value, do you see any error in log?  or just clear browser cache and hit again.

Comment: I'm making the call with curl no nho cache, and there is no error in the log.

Comment: if you hit the url in the browser, you get the expected response?

Comment: not always an empty object

Comment: means you get ONLY some times empty object?

Comment: when i call / actuator / info i always get an empty json {}

Comment: The info endpoint will return an empty object unless you have enabled one or more info contributors. What did you expect the response to contain?

Comment: In my application.properties I entered info.app.name = @ project.name @, I expected actuator / info to return me {app: {name: name}}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem, just add in the application.properties file

```
management.info.env.enabled=true
```

and the value of

```
info.app.name=@project.name@
```

is returned by `/actuator/info`